# Viewing Milestones for all GitHub Repos of an organization

Tags: api, github

In GitHub for organizations is there a way to see how your org is doing on all of its milestones at once, as opposed to having to browse into each repo and click issues->milestones and only seeing that one?

If this is impossible from the interface I might go and set up an API-based solution if that's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible from the interface, but it does look doable from the API.

You'll need to do a `GET /user/repos` and from the returned JSON Array do a `GET /repos/:user/:repo/milestones` on each repo.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the issue tracker is the same for both regular users and enterprise users. And regular users cannot browse all their issues in the same time.

So you probably need to play around with [GitHub Issues API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

DataHero does that! It can pull in all the issues across all repos for an organization.
We use DataHero internally to plot our progress on individual milestones, and across all milestones.

https://datahero.com/partners/github/

How we use it internally:
https://datahero.com/blog/2013/08/13/managing-github-projects-with-datahero/

Feel free to reach out if I can help in any way.
Disclosure: I work for DataHero